# karma testing by using expect and comparing each value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, karma-runner

How will I write the expect() so that it will loop thru each value in an array and if it matches any of the values in the array, fail it?

```
it('that it should never equal to any value from the array', function () {
  var productName = $('#someId').text();
  expect(productName).not.to.equal(['Quit','Exit','Stop']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using looping on the array inside expect(). It's working great!